# C# SQLite | How to update a single row?

Tags: c#

For my code I INSERT a row and I would like to UPDATE that row.

```
cmdRstCmdN.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Login_Details (userName,password , role,login_start) VALUES ('" + userName + "','" + password + "','" + role + "','" + login_start + "')";
cmdRstCmdN.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For above I ***INSERT*** **userName**, **password**, **role**, **login_start** INTO **Login_Details**. So now I would like to UPDATE this row with **login_end** My code is below, but it's not work. Could you help me to fix this code. I think I may wrong on some syntax or somethings.

```
cmdRstCmdN.CommandText = "UPDATE Login_Details SET login_end ='" + login_end + "' WHERE login='" + countRow + "'";
cmdRstCmdN.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Thanks all.

Comment: what is the structure of your Login_Details table ? does it have login column ?

Comment: What is the value of countRow and how does 'it's not work'?

Comment: @Hakunamatata Login_Details have column of LoginID, userName, password, role, login_start, login_end, login_interval.

Comment: @CurseStacker countRow get from 
SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
 command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Login_Details;";
long countRow = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: @SomCtk This is not the correct way to update your Login_Details table. Imagine what happens if there are two inserts into your login table before you do the update. If you do the count and update that will only update your last record. Use primary key or unique values  to update correct record, your where condition should be based on unique values in Login_Details table.

Comment: So how does it not work? No update is happening? If I'll assume your update is on a logout something function, then your update statement's where clase should be WHERE userName = '" + userName + "'"

Comment: you have a LoginID right? I assume that such data is unique. why not use that in your where clause then? as for the logic of countRow, it's just as @Hakunamatata said, it will only update your last record.

Comment: @JanLyndonJasa Anyway I just want to update last record.

Comment: hmm.. take this scenario for example. you do an insert, then before the process of updating another guy does an insert. if you do the update, you'd update his data not yours, as to why cause his is the data in the last row. You could use @CurseStacker 's method to use the userName, in the where clause, instead provided that it is unique. Anyway back to your question, have you tried your update query in SQLite directly?

Comment: @JanLyndonJasa No I didn't update query in SQLite directly? and how?